# Create a calendar showdown with button click on button position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, calendar

what I'm trying to do is basically have a calendar displayed under a button when it gets clicked by the user, and, if he picks a date, the date should be stored in some hidden textbox around the page, I tried with jquery ui's datepicker but had no luck finding a solution, I have a lot of generated buttons and I want a solution that can work with a simple onmousedown event. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've already downloaded your **jquery-ui-1.1x.x.custom.zip*** or full **jquery-ui-1.1x.x.zip*** (where x is the version you have chosen) and you've placed ziped file contents into your webpage `<head>` as follows

```
<!-- jQueryUI date theme stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<!-- http://getbootstrap.com/ -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- app's own CSS -->
<link href="/css/formstyles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- https://jquery.com/ -->
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<!-- http://getbootstrap.com/ -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- https://jQueryUI.com/ -->
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- app's own js scripts -->
<script src="/js/formscripts.js"></script>
```

** ***Don't forget to copy the "image" folder from downloaded .zip into the css folder of your project.***

then, you should implement a function like the following, into the `<head>` also, to initialise datepicker
(in this example the user may choose a birth-date in an 80 years-rage from date-like-today/1937 to date-like-today/2002 http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year ).

```
<script>
/*global $*/
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: "-80Y", maxDate: "-15Y", 
    changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-80:+0"
   });
});
    </script>
```

Then, an `<input>` HTML element like this

```
<div class="form-group">   
    <h5>Date of birth :</h5>
    <input class="form-control btn btn-default" id="datepicker" name="birth_date" value="Your birthday" type="button"/>
</div>
```

gives the requested UI
[datepicker print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oeeY.jpg)

That's all for jQueryUI.

In order to get the user's input you may want to implement a JS function that will be triggered by `onchange` attribute in your input element

```
<input class="form-control btn btn-default" id="datepicker" name="birth_date" value="Your birthday" type="button" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<textarea id="x" hidden></textarea>
<script>
    function myfunction(){
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("datepicker").value;}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man, anyway I have already decided for an easier approach (opening a popup window on each button), but I will keep that in mind the next time I have to do something similar :D